# Arquillian over Wildfly DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, testing, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I've a very simple test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SimpleTest
{
    
    @Inject private SingleEntity singleEntity;
    
    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment()
    {   
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClass(SingleEntity.class)
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void categorize()
    {
        assertNotNull(this.singleEntity);
    }
}
```

I only want to inject a object of type `SingleEntity`. `SingleEntity` is a single POJO:

```
public class SingleEntity
{
    private String id;
    private String description;
    
    public SingleEntity(String id, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    //getters & setters
}
```

After, that I perform `gradle test`. I've configured tests in order for Arquillian to perform them in a Wildfly embedded instance:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">  
  
    <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">  
        <configuration>  
        <!-- Supported property names: [managementPort, username, managementAddress, bundlePath, managementProtocol,   
                    cleanServerBaseDir, jbossHome, password, modulePath] -->  
            <property name="jbossHome">C:\servers\wildfly-Test-8.2.0.Final</property>
            <property name="modulePath">C:\servers\wildfly-Test-8.2.0.Final\modules\</property>
            <!-- <property name="managementPort">8888</property> -->  
        </configuration>  
    </container>  
</arquillian>
```

It's very straightforward, however, I receive a exception telling me `SingleEntity` cann't be resolved:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SingleEntity with qualifiers @Default
>
> at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.jeusdi.arquillian.SimpleTest.singleEntity
>
> at com.jeusdi.arquillian.SimpleTest.singleEntity(SimpleTest.java:0)

Any ideas?
Thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't want to inject entities.  JPA is based on class names, and CDI uses proxies instead of concrete classes.  This results in different classes being injected.

Now that's only best practice.  You'll probably still run into other errors if you try moving forward, but you shouldn't get this error if everything's correct.

Your entity has no bean defining annotations.  If you're using CDI 1.2 (which wildfly 8.2 provides), and your beans.xml doesn't explicitly list out `bean-discovery-mode=all` then this entity won't be picked up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought placing a `beans.xml` in my `WebArchive` was enought for enabling bean resolving on CDI. However, I've tested annotating my `SingleEntity` with `@ApplicationScoped` and it dumps the same message again.

Comment: I'm not sure if its because of your limited example, but does your entity have a default constructor? I assumed you omitted it for breavity purposes, but in order for this class to be a valid JPA Entity and a CDI bean, it needs a default constructor.  You're probably getting warnings about this in your logs somewhere.